# Find $\mathcal{O}(x)$ of $\frac{x^2+x^3+x^4}{(x+x^2+x^3)^{3/2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, rational-functions

Consider $$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x^3+x^4}{(x+x^2+x^3)^{3/2}}.$$
**Aim:** Write $f(x) = g(x) + \mathcal{O}(x)$ as $x\downarrow0$.

I can change the fraction to $$f(x)=\frac{x^{1/2}+x^{3/2}+x^{5/2}}{(1+x+x^2)^{3/2}}.$$ I can now use the Taylor approximation $\frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}}=1-ay+by^2\mp...$ and set $y=x+x^2$. Multiplying the numerator with the Taylor approximation gives
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\left(x^{1/2}+x^{3/2}+x^{5/2}\right)\left(1-a(x+x^2)+b(x+x^2)^2\mp...\right) \\
&= \sqrt{x}+\mathcal{O}(x).
\end{align}

**Question:** Is my approach correct and can I get there without a Taylor approximation?

Comment: Hint: on what assumptions can we write $f=\sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x+x^2}}$?

Comment: Minor comment: $\beta x+\mathcal{O}(x)=\mathcal{O}(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show $f(x) = x^{1/2} + O(x)$, it suffices to show $\left|\frac{f(x)-x^{1/2}}{x}\right| \le C$ for sufficiently small $x$.

$$\frac{f(x)-x^{1/2}}{x} = \frac{x^{1/2} + x^{3/2} + x^{5/2} - x^{1/2} - x^{4/2} - x^{7/2} }{x(1+x+x^2)^{3/2}}
= \frac{x^{1/2} + x^{3/2} - x - x^{5/2}}{(1+x+x^2)^{3/2}} \overset{x \downarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} 0.$$

I think you can actually show the stronger statement that $f(x) = x^{1/2} + O(x^{3/2})$, which would imply $f(x) = x^{1/2} + O(x)$.

Comment: I like your approach a lot. It nicely captures what's meant by $\mathcal{O}$. I guess one downside of your approach is that I have to know the function $g$ for which $f(x)=g(x)+\mathcal{O}(x)$ (as I do know in my example, $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$). However, if we just start with a fraction like that in the title ($\frac{x^2+x^3+x^4}{(x+x^2+x^3)^{3/2}}$) and do not do a Taylor approximation, it might be non obvious what the function $g$ should be.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is alright, though it would have been less error prone to just take the Taylor expansion of $\frac 1{(1+x+x^2)^{3/2}}$ directly.
In your case, you have to be careful that the substitution doesn't change the relevant point for which you developed the Taylor series. Here it works out since we care about $x\to 0$, for which we have $x+x^2\to 0$, which converges to the same point around which we developed the Taylor-series for $\frac1{1+y}$.

One specific error you made however is that you forgot about the $(\cdot)^{3/2}$ in
$$
f(x)= 
\left(x^{1/2}+x^{3/2}+x^{5/2}\right)\left(1-a(x+x^2)+b(x+x^2)^2\mp...\right)^{3/2}
$$
because of which the following calculation which gives you $f(x)=\sqrt x+\mathcal{O}(x^{3/2})$ isn't as nice.

---

In general, given a rational polynomial $p(x)/q(x)$ I think the most comfortable method is developing $\frac1{q(x)}$ into a Taylor series.

Comment: Very good comment. I actually have a typo in my question because $\frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}}=1-ay+by^2\mp....$. The method is indeed prone to errors when copying hand written notes to MSE ;)